# Python: Get all variable names with their types, and then export to a file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, type-inference

I have a data set of 10 variables (columns) and I would like to see all of the variable names with their types. For example, the expected output is:

```
ID Integer, 
Name Integer,
Income Float,
```

And then export the output to a text file. I know the function `type` will return the type, but it is like `<type 'int'>`. I don't want the `<type >` part.

**Updates:**

Thank you all for the help.The solutions are really helpful. I would like to further clarify my question:

I have a CSV file with first row as variable names (500 variables totally). I would like to create a SQL type code using python, and then export the output in a text file.

I am expecting the output is like:

> Create Table foo(
>
> ID Integer,
>
> Name Integer,
>
> Income Float)

My question is how to write python code to automatically generate code like that from a large CSV data file.

**Updates 2:**

My data looks like:

> ID,Name,Income
>
> 1,John,20.0
>
> 2,Tom,34.5

By using module *pandas*, I read the data like *dat=pandas.read_csv('foo.csv')*. And then using *dat.dtypes* gives me:

> ID  float64
>
> Name object
>
> Income float64
>
> dtype:object

I then replaced float64 and object with float and string. But the problem is the last line (dtype:object) does not change. How can I remove that line?

Thank you all so much. My heart felt so warm to see all the help!

Sincerely,
Lincoln

Comment: What are your "columns"? Are they just plain variables? Are they from some form of library?

Comment: If the `<type>` is the only problem, just create a map, e.g. `{int: "Integer", float: "Float", ...}`

Comment: @tobias_k That seems a perfectly good answer

Comment: @tobias_k,@Ffisegydd, Thank you for the help. I have updated my question. I appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: Can the type of one column be easily inferred from any value? I.e. if a column has floats, will they be like `3.0` or `3` or `"3.0"` etc.?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes. Basically there are three types: 1. Strings, like "Y" and "No"; 2. Integers: 0, 1 , 23, for example; and 3. floats: like 3.0, 3.2. Thank you!

Comment: But how are you inferring the type? Are you using `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` to parse the values of some line to the best-fitting type, or is there another line, or some other list, with the type information? Could you provide a minimal example of the input CSV file (just a few rows and columns)?

Answer (score 2):

Not really clear from your question where those variables are coming from. I'll just assume you've got that covered and the actual problem is to pretty-print the type.

There are (at least) two ways: Either, you could use the `type`'s `__name__` attribute to get, e.g., `'int'` instead of `<type 'int'>`, or you could create a dictionary, mapping `type`s to more expressive strings.

Example:

```
variables = {"ID": 42, "Name": "someone", "Income": 100.0}
types = {int: "Integer", float: "Floating Point", str: "Text"}
for var, val in variables.items():
    t = type(val)
    print(var, t.__name__, types[t], sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
Income  float   Floating Point
ID      int     Integer
Name    str     Text
```